# Как в функции передать ссылку на структуру, чтобы пользоваться всеми объектами структуры

Tags: c, функции, структуры

```
struct description_of_figure {
    int x_A;
    int y_A;

    int x_B;
    int y_B;

    int x_C;
    int y_C;
};

int area_of_our_triangle(struct description_of_figure) {
    int value = (x_B - x_A) * (y_C - y_A) - (x_C - x_A) * (y_B - y_A);
    int area = fabs(value) / 2;
    return area;
}
```

Как мне передать в функцию int area_of_our_triangle ссылку на структуру description_of_figure, чтобы не писать в параметрах функции - int x_A и т.д. И чтобы я мог пользоваться всеми объектами этой структуры(т.е. int x_A; int y_A; int x_B; int y_B; int x_C; int y_C). Если я так пишу, то он подчеркивает саму функцию и в int value все объекты структуры как ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Надо просто указать имя аргумента-структуры, например, `foo`:

```
int area_of_our_triangle(struct description_of_figure foo) {
  int value =   (foo.x_B - foo.x_A) * (foo.y_C - foo.y_A)
              - (foo.x_C - foo.x_A) * (foo.y_B - foo.y_A);
  // ...
}
```

Но тяжёлые структуры более эффективно будет передавать не по значению а через указатель:

```
int area_of_our_triangle(const struct description_of_figure *foo) {
  int value =   (foo->x_B - foo->x_A) * (foo->y_C - foo->y_A)
              - (foo->x_C - foo->x_A) * (foo->y_B - foo->y_A);
  // ...
}

// ...

struct description_of_figure foo;
// ... 
area_of_our_triangle(&foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

В параметрах вашей функции вы указали тип передаваемого параметра `struct description_of_figure`, но пропустили сам параметр - переменную, через которую можно обращаться к полям конкретной структуры. Доступ к полям структуры осуществляется посредством объявления `имя_переменой.поле` или `указатель_на_переменную->поле`.

Вы можете использовать несколько вариантов.

1. Передача непосредственно самой структуры в вашу функцию:

   ```
    int area_of_our_triangle(struct description_of_figure desc) {
        int value = (desc.x_B - desc.x_A) * (desc.y_C - desc.y_A) - (desc.x_C - desc.x_A) * (desc.y_B - desc.y_A);
        int area = fabs(value) / 2;
        return area;
    }
   ```

Этот вариант наименее предпочтителен, т.к. функция получает копию структуры и, соответственно, всех её полей. А копирование требует дополнительных затрат, которые в данном случае не нужны. Вызвать функцию можно так:

```
struct description_of_figure my_desc= {/*тут инициализируем поля*/};

int area = area_of_our_triangle(my_desc);
```

2. Передача в функцию ссылки на структуру (работает в C++, в "сыром" C ссылок нет):

   ```
    int area_of_our_triangle(struct description_of_figure& desc) {
        int value = (desc.x_B - desc.x_A) * (desc.y_C - desc.y_A) - (desc.x_C - desc.x_A) * (desc.y_B - desc.y_A);
        int area = fabs(value) / 2;
        return area;
    }
   ```

В этом случае `desc` - это ссылка на оригинальную структуру, а не её копия, как в предыдущем примере. Однако вызывается точно так же.

3. Передача указателя на структуру:

   ```
    int area_of_our_triangle(struct description_of_figure* pdesc) {
        int value = (pdesc->x_B - pdesc->x_A) * (pdesc->y_C - pdesc->y_A) - (pdesc->x_C - pdesc->x_A) * (pdesc->y_B - pdesc->y_A);
        int area = fabs(value) / 2;
        return area;
    }
   ```

Пример полностью аналогичен предыдущему, только теперь `pdesc` - это указатель, а не ссылка, а значит для обращения к полям вместо `.` используется `->`. Вызвать функцию можно так:

```
struct description_of_figure my_desc= {/*тут инициализируем поля*/};

int area = area_of_our_triangle(&my_desc); //передаём указатель на структуру
```

4. Объявление функции, как член самой структуры. Правда это тоже уже не C, а C++ (если требуется именно синтаксис C, то можете этот вариант проигнорировать, ровно как и вариант с ссылками):

   ```
    struct description_of_figure {
        int x_A;
        int y_A;

        int x_B;
        int y_B;

        int x_C;
        int y_C;

        int area_of_our_triangle() {
            int value = (x_B - x_A) * (y_C - y_A) - (x_C - x_A) * (y_B - y_A);
            int area = fabs(value) / 2;
            return area;
        }
    };
   ```

В этом примере нам уже не нужно явно объявлять переменную-параметр для доступа к полям. Этот параметр компилятор создаёт неявно, а к полям мы обращаемся, как к обычным переменным. С точки зрения ООП, такая функция уже сама является "полем" и вызвать её можно, например, так:

```
description_of_figure my_desc = {/*тут инициализируем поля*/};

int area = my_desc.area_of_our_triangle();
```

Comment: В Си нет ни ссылок ни функций-членов…

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Насчёт функций-членов - я это указал. Насчёт ссылок - действительно, их тоже нет в Си (ответ поправил).